# Drag an image from a treeview and drop on canvas example in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, drag-and-drop, treeview

Yes, I have repeatedly googled the subject and read numerous articles that are either too broad or too precise for what I need. Yes, I know this is Stackoverflow, so I'm ready for the snarky comments, downvoting and general abuse. And, yes, I actually wrote something in 2011 very similar to what I need but since then I had a year of chemo and my memory isn't what it used to be.

What I have is a treeview called OOB and a canvas called UnitLayerCanvas:
[image]
I want to click on a node in the treeview OOB, use the image associated with the node - I believe it's called an 'adorner' - drag it over to the canvas UnitLayerCanvas on the right and drop it. I need to know what node was clicked on in the treeview OOB and where it landed (X,Y) on the canvas UnitLayerCanvas. That's it.

Can somebody please direct me to an example in C# that explains this process? I have seen a lot of examples that involve treeview to treeview dragdrop and that's not what I need.

---

**Update**

I've got my old code working to the point where it can identify the node in the Treeview that was clicked on. I'm now wrestling with the adorner code.

**Another Update**

Got the adorner to work. Now just the drop. But, seriously, this is 20 times harder than it needed to be.

Comment: For the part of knowing which `TreeViewItem` was clicked, you could set up a `Selected` event on the top Node and then know which node was clicked by doing this `TreeViewItem item = (TreeViewItem)e.Source;`.

Comment: Okay, that sounds like a start. How would I set up a Selected event on the top Node?

Comment: You can take a look at the [the documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeviewitem.selected(v=vs.110).aspx) It explains how to setup the event.

Answer (score 0):

Using CNuts comments i will give you an idea

You must have an object that contains the item itself, and its position x and y
Then on your map you should have a collection of these items, then:

```
public class MapItem
{
    public object Item {get;set;}
    public int X {get;set;}
    public int Y {get;set;}
}
List<MapItem> MapItems {get;set;}
```

So now you have to get mouse position using 
`MouseButtonEventArgs e` (Mouse Events)

ex.:

```
Point _startPoint = e.GetPosition((StackPanel)sender);
```

then

`MapItem mapitem = new MapItem { X = _startPoint.X, Y = _startPoint.Y, Item = YourItem }`

Comment: I have an example of Drag-and-Drop Working (very small projetc) not all you need but can give you some help, if you need i can send to you

Comment: Thanks I would appreciate that.

Comment: I've got my old code working to the point where it can identify the node in the Treeview that was selected. I'm now wrestling with the adorner code.